# Same jquery for different elements with same class name

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have got this HTML that i get from PHP while loop

```
<div class="WriteCom <?php echo $Class?>">
  <form class="c_comment " method="post"><input type="text" class="Comment_In" ></form></div>
</div>
```

And this Jquery

```
var commentcount=0;
$(".WriteCom").children().submit(function() {
    var numItems = $(this).parent().siblings('.F_W_comments').children('.CommentsAw').length;
    var cc=$(this).children().val();
    var i=$(this).parent().siblings(".c_jq").children().attr("data-i");
    var com=$(this);
    commentcount++;
    $(this).children().val('');
       $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '../connect.php',
            data: "C=" + cc+"&I="+i,
            success:function(data) {
                var json_x = $.parseJSON(data);
                com.parent().parent().siblings('.c_jq').children(".Comments").children(".L_CS").html(json_x[0]);
                if (numItems>=4) {
                    com.parent().siblings('.F_W_comments').children('.CommentsAw:first').remove();
                }
                com.parent().siblings('.F_W_comments').append('<div class="cn_'+commentcount+' CommentsAw Comment_HsJ"><img src="../users/'+json_x[3]+'"><span>'+json_x[2]+'</span><span class="s2">'+json_x[1]+'</span></div>');  
                if (commentcount==1) {
                    $(".Comment_Hs:first").css("marginTop","-75px");
                    $(".cn_1").css("marginBottom","15px");
                    }else if (commentcount==2) {
                        $(".Comment_Hs:first").css("marginTop","-90px");
                        $(".cn_1").css("marginBottom","0px");
                        $(".cn_2").css("marginBottom","15px");
                        $(".cn_2").css("marginTop","-10px");
                    }else if (commentcount==3) {
                        $(".Comment_Hs:first").css("marginTop","-105px");
                        $(".cn_3").css("marginTop","-10px");
                        $(".cn_3").css("marginBottom","15px");
                        $(".cn_2").css("marginBottom","0px");
                    }else if (commentcount==4) {
                        $(".Comment_HsJ:first").css("marginTop","-105px");
                        $(".cn_4").css("marginTop","-10px");
                        $(".cn_4").css("marginBottom","15px");
                        $(".cn_3").css("marginBottom","0px");
                    }else{
                        $(".Comment_HsJ:first").css("marginTop","-105px");
                        $(".Comment_HsJ:eq(3)").css("marginTop","-10px");
                        $(".Comment_HsJ:eq(3)").css("marginBottom","15px");
                        $(".Comment_HsJ:eq(2)").css("marginBottom","0px");
                }
            }         
        });                
       return false;    
});
```

So when i have several posts and i comment on first post `commentcount` becomes 1 and when i comment on second post `commentcount` becomes 2.But i want to have commentcount for each uploaded file individually.

Comment: Put the comment count in `$(this).parent().data("commentcount")`.

Comment: @Barmar Where exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the comment count in the DIV for the post.

```
$(".WriteCom").children().submit(function() {
    var commentcount = $(this).parent().data("commentcount") || 0;
    commentcount++;
    $(this).parent().data("commentcount", commentcount);
    // rest of code
});
```